# Verify failed SQL Server connections to instances on a given server and email them

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, connectivity

I am trying to monitor the SQL Server instances on standalone server / cluster server. I would like to setup something from commandline to check for connectivity to each SQL Server instance on the server. Wherever it fails to connect to an instance I would like to have an email (we have smtp server setup) sent to our DBA team.

Each server is having more than 5 instances and we are unable to track them without customer complaining about connectivity, hence trying to be proactive.

Can we try something like `osql` or `sqlcmd`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use server audit specification to track failed logins.
2. use ssis and a script task to read audit file and email it if needed.

Comment: I think OP's concern is more about the instances going down or becoming unresponsive completely, not just failed logins.

Answer (score 0):

I have designed a powershell script in the past using WMI to check the status of each service with service name like 'MSSQLSERVER' or 'SQLSERVERAGENT'
If your named instances contains something in common between their names you can use my script and dump the results into a sql table then you can put an SQL job to check that table and send you an email if a service is down.
Here is my script and let me know if you need any further help.

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\SQL\PoweShell\servers.txt | Sort-Object

#below line will truncate the table where you want to insert your new records to:
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server1-Database DB1 -Query "Truncate table dbo.SQL_Services"

foreach($Server In $servers)
{
    Write-Host "Checking Services in $server ....."
    $services = get-wmiobject -Class win32_service -ComputerName $server | where {$_.Name -like 'MSSQLSERVER' -OR $_.name -like 'SQLSERVERAGENT' } `
    | select-object systemname,Name,state,startmode,startname

    Foreach ($service in $services)
    {
        $SN = $service.systemname
        $N = $service.Name
        $S = $service.state
        $SM = $service.startmode
        $SNA = $service.startname
        $sqldate = get-date

        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server1 -Database DB1 -Query "insert into dbo.SQL_Services select '$SN' ,'$N','$S','$SM','$SNA','$sqldate'"                                
       
    }

}
```